# Explanation of java output (hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

When I run a java project:
[image]
but the application does not fails.

What is the message?

My other project (with hibernate) don't have such messages.

How can hide this messages?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question ?

Comment: please don't post pictures. post the text

Comment: Please elaborate the question properly.

Answer (score 2):

As you might see at the prefix: most of those are `INFO` messages.

They are just telling you what is happening.

You should only be worried about `WARN`, `ERROR` and `FATAL` messages.

**edit:**

your other project isn't posting those messages because of a lower log-level (warn, error or fatal)

Comment: Thanks! 
_>>> because of a lower log-level (warn, error or fatal)_
Where can I change a log-level?

Comment: i assume you are using log4j. so in the log4j.properties